# How to implement "control group" in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement "control group" in Ionic,

Below is my expectation:

[image]

[image]

But I couldn't find any in Ionic,
this is the link I refer to:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#header

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think Ionic has that implemented at the moment the only suggestion i could make would be to either use toggle (bad way) or to use to different buttons I used this way when i created 2 Listcontainers to switch between them

```
<div class="button-bar">
            <a class="button" ng-init="showme=true; setshowme(true)" ng-click="showme=true; setshowme(true)" ng-class="{'active': showme == true}">{{::lang.pnlPosOffenML}}</a>
            <a class="button" ng-click="showme=false; setshowme(false)" ng-class="{'active': showme == false}">{{::lang.pnlPosErledigtML}}</a>
        </div>
```

This is what i came up with

Answer (score 1):

Hi This is worked for me, In your html file write the code as

```
<ion-item>
    <button class="button button-light" ng-disabled="!allow" ng-click="selectedMale()">Male</button>
    <button class="button button-light" ng-disabled="!notAllow" ng-click="selectedFemale()">Female</button>
    </ion-item>
     <ion-item>
    <button class="button button-light" ng-disabled="!notAllow" ng-click="selectedFemale()">Male</button>
    <button class="button button-light" ng-disabled="!allow" ng-click="selectedMale()">Female</button>
    </ion-item>
```

and in your controller the code is

```
$scope.allow = true;
  $scope.notAllow = true;
  $scope.selectedMale = function(){
    $scope.notAllow = false;
  }
  $scope.selectedFemale = function(){
    $scope.allow=false;
  }
```

please reply if having any queries